Spring Boot LDAP transactions
I'm trying to enable transaction for LDAP repositories. I found this https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/reference/transaction-support.html documentation, but it only describes how to enable it with a beans.xml file. In spring boot you usually don't have that and I can't figure out how to do this programmatically in a @Configuration annotated class.
Just in case you ask: No it doesn't seem to be enabled by default. When I debug my @Transactional annotated method, transactions in general seem to be working (you know TransactionInterceptor, CGLib and all that in use), but I think this only handles Jpa repositories by default. My method just consists of a repo.save method and a hard coded RuntimeException. But still the expected rollback doesn't happen.
Update:
I've made some progress: So I think I managed to configure the ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager in the spring boot style with:
@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource, ContextSource contextSource) {
    var tx = new ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager();
    tx.setDataSource(dataSource);
    tx.setContextSource(contextSource);
    tx.setRenamingStrategy(new DefaultTempEntryRenamingStrategy());
    return tx;
}

When I debug the ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback method I can see that it is actually executed in case of a runtime exception after repository.save. But still the new entity is in LDAP without being rolled back.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Solved it - so this configuration actually makes it work:
@Bean
public ContextSource contextSource(LdapContextSource ldapContextSource) {
    return new TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy(ldapContextSource);
}

@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource, ContextSource contextSource) {
    var tx = new ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager();
    tx.setDataSource(dataSource);
    tx.setContextSource(contextSource);
    tx.setRenamingStrategy(new DefaultTempEntryRenamingStrategy());
    return tx;
}

